# How to convert an angular project to Asp.Net Angular Project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angular, migration

I have created an angular application, using command `ng new my-application`. I want to migrate that application to Asp.Net application. How to transform my application to Asp.net application with MVC.

Comment: you don't do that. You just create an mvc application and then import the angular libraries. Then you can use angular in your views just like you use in the angular projects

Comment: But then how do i debug?

Comment: using your browser

Comment: I want it to be done through vs itself.